# Best current practice for Dart32 on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: dart, raspbian

What is the current best way to get Dart2 32bit onto a pi running stretch? apt-get attempts to install the 64bit version and fails

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dark sdk following [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/archive#download-urls) syntax:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/<stable|dev>/release/<release>/sdk/dartsdk-<platform>-<architecture>-release.zip
```

i.e. to get the Dart SDK 2.0.0 on linux for 32bit you can use:
https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/2.0.0/sdk/dartsdk-linux-ia32-release.zip

After that you'll need to extract the archive and update properly you `PATH` variable.